# Math.Random in function always the same result

Tags: javascript, random

I have this code:

```
function raffle(){
number = Math.random(100) * 100;} 
raffle();
```

But everytime I raffle(); the number is the same.

Comment: You appear to be using javascript - this is really a javascript question. Is "number" a global variable which is declared above this function, and which you check elsewhere?

Comment: What language is this?  I suspect you're seeding the generator with a constant value which will always give you the same number when you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns an a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). The Javascript `random` function doesn't take any parameters.

If you want a random number x such that 0 ≤ x < 100, then you would do:

```
function raffle() {
    return Math.random() * 100;
}
```

Comment: But if you *do* pass a parameter like the OP did wouldn't it just be ignored? So why is the OP getting the same result every time the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Your raffle function never returns a value.

Here's a version which returns the random value.

```
function raffle() {
    return Math.random() * 100;
}
```

*(The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the iteration number to every results, like so:

```
let runNumber = 0
function raffle(){
    return Math.random() * 100 + runNumber++;
} 
raffle();
```

You probably run it one after another, which is where the "pseudo" random part kick in.